# What setting is this asking me to change?

Tags: civireport

I created what I thought was a simple custom report and am receiving the the following error message.  I can get to the file, and normally I can stumble through deciphering what Civi is trying to tell me- but I'm at a loss on this one. Kind regards.

[image: Error message]

[image: Report on dashboard]

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like you need that $joinsForFiltersOnly parameter in your implementation of customDataFrom